# JQuery asp.net validator callout plugin updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, updatepanel, validation

I am using this plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/updnValidatorCallout

This controls to be validated are inside an updatepanel. Before posting back everything works fine, after a async postback the callout plugin messes up.

I'm initializing the plugin like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.updnValidatorCallout.attachAll();
});
```

I tried putting this in the pageLoad and endRequest of the UpdatePanel but with no success.

Anyone knows more about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to how the UpdatePanel works. When UpdatePanel refreshes, it will replace the content enclosed inside it. This will break your plugin because it will not be able to find the original plugin.

To resolve this, call this 'attachAll' method when the UpdatePanel has finished refreshing to bind it again.